# How to check filename?

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I am new to HP UFT I am trying to write a script to figure out how to figure out the file name of a file in the Desktop. I know how to open the Desktop folder with SystemUtil.run but I am not sure how to get the filename of a certain file in the folder and store it as a string. How could I do this? I tried using the record function but it does not seem to capture the filename.

Comment: What did you tried so far as code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the folder, [I've found here an example that you can use(adapted and translated to English)](http://jacxl.free.fr/cours_xl/cours_xl_jac.html#exemples_vbs)

```
nomfich=InputBox("Please type the full name of your directory to explore", _ 
    "répertoire vbs","c:\mes documents") 
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set rep=fs.getFolder(nomfich) 
txt="" 
for each fich in rep.files 
txt=txt & chr(10) & fich.name & " (created the " & left(fich.DateCreated,8) & ")" 
next 
MsgBox txt,,"liste of files in the directory " & rep.name
```

Of course, this give you the full list of files. If your file name includes, for example, the string "MyFile", you can adapt so :

```
MyPath = "C:\MyPath\"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set rep=fs.getFolder(MyPath) 
txt="" 
For Each myFile In rep.files 
    If Instr(myFile.name, "MyFile") > 0 Then ' Is true if the filename includes "MyFile"
        (do here what you have to do with the file you just identified)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

In that example, myFile.name is the name of the file. The loop gives you everything in the "C:\MyPath\" directory. Of course, depending on your exact need, there will be a lot of adaptations to make.